# Problem on $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

I would like someone to verify my solution/proof to the questions posed by this Exercise 4.3.2 in Stephen Abbott's text, Understanding Analysis.

> To gain a deeper understanding of the relationship between $\displaystyle \epsilon $ and $\displaystyle \delta $ in the definition of continuity, let's explore some modest variation of the definition 4.3.1. In all of these, let $\displaystyle f$ be a function defined on all of $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$.

> (a) Let's say $\displaystyle f$ is *onetinuous* at $\displaystyle c$ if for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, we can choose $\displaystyle \delta =1$ and it follows that $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| < \epsilon $ whenever $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $. Find an example of a function that is onetinuous on all of $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$.

> (b) Let's say $\displaystyle f$ is *equaltinuous* at $\displaystyle c$ if for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, we can choose $\displaystyle \delta =\epsilon $ and it follows that $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| < \epsilon $ whenever $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $. Find an example of a function that is equaltinuous on $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$ that is nowhere onetinuous, or explain why there is no such function.

> (c) Let's say that $\displaystyle f$ is *lesstinuous* at $\displaystyle c$, if for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, we can choose $\displaystyle 0< \delta < \epsilon $ and it follows that $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| < \epsilon $ wheneve $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $. Find an example of a function that is lesstinuous on $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$ that is nowhere equaltinuous, or explain why there is no such function.

> (d) Is every lesstinuous function continuous? Is every continuous function lesstinuous? Explain.

***Solution.***

(a) Consider the constant function $\displaystyle f( x) =k$. For all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, we can pick $\displaystyle \delta =1$, such that whenever $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $, we have $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| =| k-k| =0< \epsilon $. So, $\displaystyle f$ is onetinuous on all of $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$.

(b) Consider the function $\displaystyle g( x) =x$. This function is equaltinuous on $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$. Pick an arbitrary $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ and let $\displaystyle c$ be an arbitrary point. We are interested to make the distance $\displaystyle | g( x) -g( c)| $ as small as we please. Consider the inequality $\displaystyle | g( x) -g( c)| =| x-c| < \epsilon $. Set $\displaystyle \delta =\epsilon $. Then, $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $ implies $\displaystyle | g( x) -g( c)| < \epsilon $. As $\displaystyle c$ was arbitrary, $\displaystyle g( x)$ is equaltinuous on all of $\displaystyle \mathbf{R}$. Moreover, $\displaystyle g( x)$ is nowhere onetinuous, since if we pick $\displaystyle \epsilon < 1$, then we must have $\displaystyle 0< \delta < 1$.

(c) Consider $\displaystyle f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ defined by $\displaystyle f( x) =2x$. Let $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ be arbitrary. We would like to make the distance $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| < \epsilon $. This implies $\displaystyle | 2x-2c| < \epsilon $. So, $\displaystyle | x-c| < \epsilon /2$.

Let $\displaystyle \delta =\epsilon /2$. Thus, $\displaystyle f( x)$ is lesstinuous and it is nowhere equaltinuous.

(d) By definition, a function $\displaystyle f$ is lesstinuous, if for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ there exists $\displaystyle 0< \delta < \epsilon $, such that whenever the distance $\displaystyle | x-c| < \delta $, the property $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( c)| < \epsilon $. Consequently, lesstinuous functions are continuous.

Continuous functions are lesstinuous. Because, if $\displaystyle \delta \geq \epsilon $ is the largest $\displaystyle \delta $-response suitable for a given $\displaystyle \epsilon $-challenge, any smaller $\displaystyle \delta < \epsilon $ should also guarantee that $\displaystyle f( x) \in V_{\epsilon }( f( c))$.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. A correction - the function in (c) is lesstinuous but nowhere equaltinuous.

Comment: Edited the typo.